# How a QHBoxLayout could remove itself?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside6

I have a code that makes some QHBoxLayouts with some elements in them. I want to remove each Row class (QHBoxLayouts object) when clicking on their own remove button.

Here is the code for testing it

```
from sys import exit, argv
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QScrollArea, QPushButton, QLineEdit

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.sub_window = None
        self.screenWidth = 1920
        self.screenHeight = 1080
        self.windowWidth = 1000
        self.windowHeight = 800
        self.setupUi()
        self.show()

    def setupUi(self) -> None:
        self.setWindowTitle("Password Manager")
        self.setGeometry((self.screenWidth - self.windowWidth) // 2, (self.screenHeight - self.windowHeight) // 2, self.windowWidth, self.windowHeight)
        self.mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.scrollAreaLayoutContents = QVBoxLayout()
        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setLayout(self.scrollAreaLayoutContents)
        for i in range(10):
            self.scrollAreaLayoutContents.addLayout(Row(f"{i}"))
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

class Row(QHBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.nameLineEdit = QLineEdit(f"{name}")
        self.nameLineEdit.setDisabled(True)
        self.addWidget(self.nameLineEdit)
        self.removeButton = QPushButton("remove")
        self.removeButton.clicked.connect(self.removeItSelf)
        self.addWidget(self.removeButton)
    
    def removeItSelf(self) -> None:
        self.removeItem(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    exit(app.exec())
```

I want to remove each Row class (QHBoxLayouts object) when clicking on their own remove button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.removeItem(self)` will obviously not work, because `removeItem()` removes an item *from* the layout represented by `self`, and an item cannot remove itself *from* itself.

The removal should be done on the level of the parent layout, but there are three aspects that should be kept in mind:

- there is no direct way to get the parent layout from a nested one;
- removing the layout does not remove the widgets;
- the layout could have other nested layout of its own;

The first point can be easily solved when talking about removal: since QLayout inherits from QObject, we can call `deleteLater()`.

In your simple case, assuming that the contents are known and do not change, it could be done like this:

```py
    def removeItSelf(self) -> None:
        self.nameLineEdit.deleteLater()
        self.removeButton.deleteLater()
        self.deleteLater()
```

In any other situations (for instance, if contents are dynamically added), the only way to ensure that all the contents get destroyed is by using a recursive function that iterates all layout items.

While that is feasible, there is a much simpler solution: instead of using a layout subclass, use a basic QWidget as a container. In that case, all widgets are children of the container, and deleting the container will automatically take care of their removal:

```py
class Row(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name:str) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.nameLineEdit = QLineEdit(f"{name}")
        self.nameLineEdit.setDisabled(True)
        layout.addWidget(self.nameLineEdit)
        self.removeButton = QPushButton("remove")
        self.removeButton.clicked.connect(self.removeItSelf)
        layout.addWidget(self.removeButton)
    
    def removeItSelf(self) -> None:
        self.deleteLater()

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    # ...

    def setupUi(self) -> None:
        # ...
        for i in range(10):
            self.scrollAreaLayoutContents.addWidget(Row(f"{i}"))
```